# How to assign "INVALID" to all outputs of function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to define a function that takes inputs Year, Crash_Month, Crash_Day and Crash_Time and returns the outputs season(Summer for months 12, 1, 2, Autumn for months 3,4,5 etc) weekday (Monday:1 to Sunday:7) and time_of_day (as Morning, Afternoon, Evening and Night).
I have created the following code to define my function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': (data_dict['Year']),
            'season': (data_dict['Crash_Month']),
            'weekday': (data_dict['Crash_Day']),
            'time_of_day': (data_dict['Crash_Time'])})
df['time_of_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_of_day'], format = "%H:%M:%S", errors = 'coerce')
d = {1:'Monday', 2:'Tuesday', 3:'Wednesday', 4:'Thursday', 5:'Friday', 6:'Saturday', 7:'Sunday'}
df['weekday'] = df['weekday'].map(d)
s = {12:'Summer', 1:'Summer', 2:'Summer', 3:'Autumn', 4:'Autumn', 5:'Autumn', 6:'Winter', 7:'Winter', 8: 'Winter', 9: 'Spring', 10: 'Spring', 11:'Spring'}
df['season'] = df['season'].map(s)
df['time_of_day']=df['time_of_day'].dt.hour.apply(lambda x: np.select([0<=x<6,
                                                                       6<=x<12,
                                                                       12<=x<18,
                                                                       12<=x<24],
                                                                      ['Night', 'Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']))    
def compute_time_day_year(df):
    return(df)
```

It returns a data frame with the required outputs. However, in the excel file some of the Crash_Time values are "UNKNOWN". For these "UNKNOWN" entries I want to assign all outputs in the data frame (season, weekday, time) as 'INVALID". I have tried to use:

```
while True:
    try:
        compute_time_day_year(df)
    except ValueError:
        return 'INVALID'
```

but the output does not change any values to INVALID.
Does anyone have any advice on how to assign all output to 'INVALID'?

Comment: If `Crash_Time` is literal string `UNKNOWN` how is even `time_of_day` being converted to datetime object? it should throw a `ParseError`,  do you mind providing some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @jcaliz this is from the data file                                                     
year,month,day,time 2000,1,1,4:30:59 2000,1,1,0:07:35 2000,1,1,4:51:37 2000,1,1,4:27:56 2000,1,1,2:16:31 2000,1,1,0:37:21 2000,1,1,0:52:57 2000,1,1,3:35:14 2000,1,1,2:41:58 2000,1,1,3:43:02 2000,1,1,3:49:19 2000,1,1,3:03:55 2000,1,1,4:46:01 2000,1,1,1:07:24 2000,1,1,8:29:04 2000,1,1,6:35:21 2000,1,1,6:06:25 2000,1,1,7:10:13 2000,1,1,UKNOWN 2000,1,1,UKNOWN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `to_datetime` has parameter `errors = 'coerce'` it return missing values for `UNKNOWN` strings, so then set `NaN`s to `weekday` and `season` columns:

```
df['time_of_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_of_day'], format = "%H:%M:%S", errors = 'coerce')
df.loc[df['time_of_day'].isna(), ['weekday','season']] = np.nan
```

If want set all columns:

```
df.loc[df['time_of_day'].isna()] = np.nan
#or
#df = df.mask(df['time_of_day'].isna())
```